# Is it possible to block the option to report an email as spam or phishing when it is originated from the organization (organization's users)?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace

In my corporation, when a user hosts an infected file on their Google Drive, they are able to download the file by clicking on the "Download the infected file" button. Is there a way to block this button and prevent users from continuing to access files that Google has already identified as infected (Using Google Workspace)?

[image: Screenshot.]

Comment: [tag:google-drive] is to be used in questions about a deprecated installable client. Questions about Google Workspace administration are off-topic in [su].

Answer (score 0):

For a file that was found to be infected with a virus, only the owner
may download the file without any issues, although you should still
get the warning that ‘This file might harm your computer’.

If you have given a sharing URL of the viral file, then the download will
be blocked, as only the owner is allowed to download infected files.
Others can preview the file inside Google Drive if the format is supported,
but the download is restricted.

You will be unable to share such a file: If the file is infected with
a virus, or if you are sharing any illegal, harmful, or pirated file,
then Drive will block the sharing option, citing violation of the
Terms of Service.

This seems like a safe enough scheme, where you may still salvage your
infected file, while knowing full well that it's infected and so hopefully
taking precautions. But you can't infect others, since the file will be
blocked from sharing, although not from viewing.

There is no way to suppress the download option for you, if you are
the owner of the file.